# How can I convert a list of lists to a dictionary whose keys are integers and values are the index of the sublist to which the integer belongs?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists, where each integer 0..N belongs to exactly one list within the outer list. So for example, if N=6, I have something like

```
L=[[0,4,5],[2,3],[1,6]]
```

I want the dictionary to look like the following:

```
{0:0, 1:2, 2:1, 3:1, 4:0, 5:0}
```

For example, the key:value pair 2:1 indicates 2 belongs to L[1].

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What output do you want for `L=[[0,4,5],[2,3],[0,6]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L=[[0,4,5],[2,3],[1,6]]

result = dict()
for i,l  in enumerate(L):
  for item in l:
    result[item]=i

print(result)
```

This will produce output like:

```
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) + a [dictionary comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/dict_comprehension.html):

```
L = [[0, 4, 5], [2, 3], [1, 6]]
result = {value: i for i, values in enumerate(L) for value in values}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{0: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 1: 2, 6: 2}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
result = {}
for i, values in enumerate(L):
    for value in values:
        result[value] = i
```

The key here, in my opinion, is to use enumerate to access the indices and the elements of `L`.